# Как переподключить валидацию jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

В форме есть TextArea

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(r => r.Message, new Dictionary<string, object> {
  {"cols", 2},
  {"rows", 4},
  {"style", "overflow:hidden" },
  {"data-val", "false"}
})
```

"data-val", "false" - задает отключение ненавязчивой валидации

Мне нужно: при выборе CheckBox, чтобы валидация в TextArea включалась.
Написан скрипт, который меняет атрибут, часть кода вот:

```
 $("#Message").attr("data-val", "true");
```

Но из-за того, что jQuery подключается один раз в начале документа (функция выполняется один раз в жизни страницы) валидация не включается.

Как можно "переподключить"/обойти данный момент?

Comment: Что мешает выполнить нужную функцию еще раз? И где сама эта функция?

Comment: функция находится в файле jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
если вызывать ее при установке ChekBox (то есть подключать этот файл каждый раз), то нажимая туда сюда выйдет не очень хорошо.

Comment: функция без имени, поэтому она вызывается при подключении файла.
Соответственно, я не могу вызвать ее, не подключая файл еще раз.

Comment: вы руками что ли поле провалидировать не можете? что у вас там проверяется то?

Comment: вообще, переключения этого атрибута я так понимаю должно быть достаточно. у вас другие атрибуты валидации то установлены?